# Retrieve Images embedded in a UserForm VBA

Tags: vba, userform

Does anyone know where images are stored in a UserForm? I made a UserForm with custom buttons and I want to get the images and reuse them because I dont have the originals anymore.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example you could use code like that

```
SavePicture Image1.Picture, "D:\TMP\MyUFPic.bmp"
```

Comment: Yes, as I do not know what the OP  refers to when saying _UserForm with custom buttons_  I just gave an example how to retrieve the picture from an image control.

Comment: Excelent!! exactly what i needed. Thanks!

Comment: Great. How to change the embedded image by vba code so as to save the new one to the form?

Comment: This just worked for me as well!  Thank you kind sirs or madams!  For the background of a userform, I used the SavePicture SplashForm.Picture, "directory path... etc." where SplashForm was the name of the UserForm with the background I was extracting.  I was able to run it straight in the immediate window.  Fancy!